# How to get syntax error form php exec

Tags: php, exec

I use this to compile my java file

```
 $command_compile = "javac $target_path_file 2>&1";
exec($command_compile, $compile_result, $return_compile);
```

And When my java file has syntax error. It always has error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Myclass
```

How to get error such as Syntax Error. need ) On line 5

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = exec($command_compile, $compile_result, $return_compile);
```

inside $res you get the **last line** of output of the executed command

If **javac** returns more lines (either error or informative messages) you may want to parse the $compile_result array that contains every output line.

```
foreach($compile_result as $compile_result_line) {
    // do what you need with $compile_result_line
}
```

Anyway see http://php.net/function.exec for a detailed explanation of **exec**

---

The error you get is not from PHP code but is a "java" issue when you call **javac**. It seem you're trying to compile a file that reference an undefined class.

Comment: yes i do foreach($compile_result as $result){echo $result}
But error always 
 Error: Could not find or load main class Myclass